# Solely COUNT(*) from Zend_DB Select Statement (Subquery)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to wrap a count(*) query around an existing Zend_Db select statement, but all I was able to get is:

```
SELECT `t`.*, COUNT(*) AS `TotalRecords` FROM (SELECT ....) AS `t`
```

However I like to get rid of the t.* as I only need the count(*).

This is my code so far:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$select = $dbmodel->getSomething(); //zend select object
$outterSelect = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$outterSelect->from($select)->columns(array('TotalRecords' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')));
echo $outterSelect->__toString();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
$outterSelect->from($select, 'COUNT(*) as TotalRecords');
```

Comment: would it also be possible to get the result by only using $select. that means without $db?

Comment: If your mobel is extend Zend_Db_Table, you can do something like $model->select()->from->(...)

Comment: something like this `$res = $doc->select()->from($select, 'COUNT(*) as rowcount')->fetchAll()->toArray();` doesn't work for me. fetchAll() is not known in this case.